File cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system
I am running the Powershell script from my C# code. The same code is working for the .net 4.7.2 framework application, But when I use the same code within the same solution for the .net8 application, the same script is giving the below exception while invoking this script.

File C:\work\Powershell\SampleAppDotNet8\bin\Debug\net8.0\PS.ps1
cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Code:
public void RunScript(string scriptPath, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
    using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        ps.AddCommand(scriptPath);

        foreach (var param in parameters)
        {
            ps.AddParameter(param.Key, param.Value);
        }

        var results = ps.Invoke();

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        if (ps.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var error in ps.Streams.Error)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {error}");
            }
        }
    }
}

I have tried checking the Execution policies as well, they are below.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ExecutionPolicy  -List

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser          Bypass
 LocalMachine          Bypass

The only difference between the two projects is that the .net8 application refers to Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK and the .net 4.7.2 is referring the DLL from GAC (......\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Management.Automation.dll)
PS Script:
param (
    [string]$name,
    [string]$username,
    [SecureString]$password
)

# Converting SecureString to plain text for display (for demonstration purposes)
if ($null -ne $securePassword) {
    $plainPassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($password))
}
else {
    # Write-Error "Secure password cannot be null."
}

# Write-Host "Name: $name"
# Write-Host "Username: $username"
# Write-Host "Password: $plainPassword"


# Creating a custom object to return
$result = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name = $name
    Username = $username
    Password = $plainPassword
}

# Returning the object
Write-Output $result

Complete Error:

C:\work\Powershell\SampleAppDotNet8\bin\Debug\net8.0>SampleAppDotNet8.exe
Unhandled exception. System.Management.Automation.PSSecurityException:
File C:\work\Powershell\SampleAppDotNet8\bin\Debug\net8.0\PS.ps1
cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.  --->
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: File
C:\work\Powershell\SampleAppDotNet8\bin\Debug\net8.0\PS.ps1 cannot be
loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more
information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.    --- End of inner
exception stack trace ---    at
System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable
input)    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline.Invoke()
at
System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace
rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)    at
System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace
rsToUse, Boolean isSync)    at
System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection1 input, PSDataCollection1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)    at
System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection1 input, PSDataCollection1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)    at
System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TOutput](IEnumerable
input, PSDataCollection1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke(IEnumerable input, PSInvocationSettings settings)    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke()    at PowershellAdvance.PowerShellService.RunScript(String scriptPath, Dictionary2 parameters) in
C:\work\Powershell\PowershellParamsResolver\PowerShellService.cs:line
24    at PowershellAdvance.PowerShellScriptRunner.RunAsync(String
jsonString, String scriptPath) in
C:\work\Powershell\PowershellParamsResolver\PowerShellScriptRunner.cs:line
26    at SampleAppDotNet8.Program.Main(String[] args) in
C:\work\Powershell\SampleAppDotNet8\Program.cs:line 26    at
SampleAppDotNet8.Program.(String[] args)

So Do I need to handle calling the PS differently in the .net8 application?

The GAC version will probably be PowerShell 5.x and the SDK version will be PowerShell 7.x, I believe they maintain different execution policies. Suggest installing PowerShell 7.x and setting the execution policy in that terminal as a test.

@nimizen Thanks a lot, Your answer helped in in fixing the issue.

You should think of powershell as yet another .NET language, meaning just about anything you might do through powershell you can do directly in C#.

As an aside: The simplest  way to convert a secure string ([securestring] instance) to plain text - which is inherently a security risk - is ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText $secureString in PowerShell (Core) 7, and [pscredential]::new('unused', $secureString).GetNetworkCredential().Password in Windows PowerShell. Also (mostly a moot point, given that [securestring] is to be avoided on Unix-like platforms altogether), the lower-level approach based on [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal] should use PtrToStringBSTR(), not PtrToStringAuto().

@mklement0 so my script correct to convert from secureString? If not then what should I write? I need to write PS for both .net and .net core

@VivekNuna: My previous comment implies that it'll work on Windows, both in .NET Framework and .NET (Core), but that it's better and conceptually more correct to use PtrToStringBSTR rather than PtrToStringAuto. The same comment also shows simpler alternatives to this approach, and the [pscredential]-based one also works both in .NET Framework (Windows PowerShell) and .NET (Core) (PowerShell (Core) 7). Also, please don't forget to bring closure to your post; if you feel something's missing from my answer, please provide feedback.


The two PowerShell editions,

the legacy, ships-with-Windows Windows PowerShell edition (powershell.exe, whose latest and final version is 5.1.x, which is based on .NET Framework)
vs.
the install-on-demand, cross-platform PowerShell (Core) 7 edition (pwsh, version 7.x, based on .NET (Core)),

have separate execution policies.
Each edition has its own SDK for hosting PowerShell in a custom application.

See this answer for the NuGet packages to choose.

The execution policies of the respective stand-alone edition apply to SDK projects too, with the exception of the LocalMachine policy of a stand-alone PowerShell 7 installation (note that while Windows PowerShell is guaranteed to be present on an given machine, the install-on-demand PowerShell 7 is not).

See this answer for details.

However, the best solution is not to rely on a preconfigured execution policy to begin with, and instead, as part of your project, use an SDK method to set the execution policy dynamically, for the current process only, as follows (this is the equivalent of using Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process RemoteSigned -Force) - this makes your application work predictably, irrespective of whether a stand-alone PowerShell 7 installation is also present and, if so, irrespective of what its configuration is:
  // Create an initial default session state.
  var iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2();

  // Set its script-file execution policy (for the current session (process) only).
  iss.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.RemoteSigned;

  // Create a PowerShell instance with a runspace based on the 
  // initial session state and run a sample script to show
  // that the process-level policy took effect.
  using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(iss))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(
      ps.AddScript(@"Get-ExecutionPolicy -List | Out-String").Invoke()[0]
    );
  }


My pleasure, @VivekNuna.
